# Create stored procedure with parameters which it has null values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I'm rookie in SQL Server.

I have a table `dbo.Example` which has 4 columns like this :

```
|Barcode|Goods |  Stock   |   Person |
-----------------------------------------
|0020307|Book  |Available |   Mike   |
|0090010|Table |NULL      |   Jane   |
|0140397|Chalk |NULL      |   Mike   |
|0190017|Glass |NULL      |Christoper|
|0080017|Hammer|Available |   Ron    |
```

I tried to create a stored procedure with parameters which it has null values in `[Stock]` column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE examproc
    @person NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @stock nvarchar(50) = NULL 
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Example
    WHERE person = ISNULL(@person, person)
      AND Stock = ISNULL(@stock, Stock) OR Stock IS NULL
```

And execute the procedure like this with parameter :

```
EXEC examproc @person = 'Mike'
```

But the result is not what I expected:

```
|Barcode|Goods |  Stock   |   Person |
-----------------------------------------
|0020307|Book  |Available |   Mike   |
|0090010|Table |NULL      |   Jane   |
|0140397|Chalk |NULL      |   Mike   |
|0190017|Glass |NULL      |Christoper|
```

I know there is something wrong with my SQL statement, and I'm still confused.

I need a suggestion..

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be super careful when mixing `AND` and `OR` in a `WHERE` clause - try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE examproc
    @person NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @stock nvarchar(50) = NULL 
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Example
    WHERE person = ISNULL(@person, person)
      AND (Stock = ISNULL(@stock, Stock) OR Stock IS NULL)
```

and you can further simplify that by just leaving out the second condition (`Stock IS NULL`) - that's already handled by the first stock condition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE examproc
    @person NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @stock nvarchar(50) = NULL 
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Example
    WHERE Person = ISNULL(@person, person)
      AND Stock = ISNULL(@stock, Stock)
```